# What's the difference between prettier-eslint, eslint-plugin-prettier and eslint-config-prettier?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint, code-formatting, prettier

I want to use Prettier and ESLint together, but I experienced some conflicts just by using them one after another. I see that there are these three packages that seem to allow them to be used in tandem:

- `prettier-eslint`
- `eslint-plugin-prettier`
- `eslint-config-prettier`

However, I am unsure which to use as these package names all contain `eslint` and `prettier`.

Which should I use?

Answer (score 429, accepted):

**tl;dr: Use `eslint-config-prettier`, you can ignore the rest.**

**UPDATE 2023**: [ESLint is deprecating formatting rules and recommend you use a source code formatter instead](https://eslint.org/blog/2023/10/deprecating-formatting-rules/). From v8.53.0 onwards, you will see a deprecation warning if those formatting rules are enabled in your config. You should still use `eslint-config-prettier` until the rules are removed in a new major release.

ESLint contains many rules and those that are formatting-related might conflict with Prettier, such as `arrow-parens`, `space-before-function-paren`, etc. Hence using them together will cause some issues. The following tools have been created to use ESLint and Prettier together.

|  | [`prettier-eslint`](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-eslint) | [`eslint-plugin-prettier`](https://github.com/prettier/eslint-plugin-prettier) | [`eslint-config-prettier`](https://github.com/prettier/eslint-config-prettier) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| What it is | A JavaScript module exporting a single function. | An ESLint plugin. | An ESLint configuration. |
| What it does | Runs the code (string) through `prettier` then `eslint --fix`. The output is also a string. | Plugins usually contain implementations for additional rules that ESLint will check for. This plugin uses Prettier under the hood and will raise ESLint errors when your code differs from Prettier's expected output. | This config turns off formatting-related rules that might conflict with Prettier, allowing you to use Prettier with other ESLint configs like [`eslint-config-airbnb`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-airbnb). |
| How to use it | Either calling the function in your code or via [`prettier-eslint-cli`](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-eslint-cli) if you prefer the command line. | Add it to your `.eslintrc`. | Add it to your `.eslintrc`. |
| Is the final output Prettier compliant? | Depends on your ESLint config | Yes | Yes |
| Do you need to run `prettier` command separately? | No | No | Yes |
| Do you need to use anything else? | No | You may want to turn off conflicting rules using `eslint-config-prettier`. | No |

For more information, refer to the [official Prettier docs](https://prettier.io/docs/en/integrating-with-linters.html).

It's the recommended practice to let Prettier handle formatting and ESLint for non-formatting issues, `prettier-eslint` is not in the same direction as that practice, hence `prettier-eslint` is not recommended anymore. You can use `eslint-plugin-prettier` and `eslint-config-prettier` together.

Comment: I have a eslintrc file in which I have custom rules. i.e no-extra-semi however running eslint --fix with prettier requires semi colon, do i need a separate rules file for prettier?

Comment: Just a comment on the general difference between eslint plugins and configs, because I felt it was what was missing for me: plugins define new eslint rules, and configs set wether or not (and how) the rules should be applied.

Comment: With `eslint-config-prettier`, why do we need to run prettier? Wouldn't `eslint --fix` format the code the same way prettier would?

Comment: @MateoHrastnik ESLint does not handle all possible formatting issues. Refer to this thread - https://github.com/prettier/prettier-eslint/issues/101

Comment: I think it's worth to mention how it behaves with some editors like vscode.

Comment: It's 2019, and this is still the best explanation I find, much better than the official one. You might add that prettier-eslint is not recommended any more. And the latter 2 can work together now.

Comment: @FateRiddle Just curious, why do you say `prettier-eslint` is not recommended any more?

Comment: @theblang It's the recommended practice to let Prettier handle formatting and ESLint for non-formatting issues. `prettier-eslint` is not in the same direction as that practice.

Comment: @YangshunTay I'm just curious though, who is recommending that practice?

Comment: Oh I think it's @FateRiddle who said it. I wasn't thinking too much when I took his words into consideration. I'm also curious who recommended he/she got the recommendation from.

Comment: @FateRiddle care to weigh in on why prettier-eslint is not recommended any more?

Comment: Prettier generally recommends against using anything other than eslint-config-prettier. You can read what they have to say here https://prettier.io/docs/en/integrating-with-linters.html. Personally, I prefer to not have the red underlines from eslint. The downside is if you have CI setup, you need to make sure it catches prettier as well as eslint.

Comment: Strong disagree on spreading the "official" recommendation of preferring eslint-config-prettier over prettier-eslint. Masking out eslint rules and having 2 separate CI jobs for lint/format checking doesn't sound any more beneficial than layering one on top of the other.

Comment: @sarimarton unfortunately after 6 years, ESLint is "officially" going in this direction and will deprecate formatting rules: https://eslint.org/blog/2023/10/deprecating-formatting-rules/

Comment: Does your 2023 update invalidate the "tl;dr:" or is it still the proposed answer?

Comment: @DanielKaplan Good question. It does not invalidate the tl;dr. Updated the answer!

Comment: @YangshunTay Thank you! I would love your insight [on this other question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77491378/in-vscode-how-do-i-effectively-run-eslint-fix-and-prettier-write-on-format). I don't see how it's possible to get the behavior I'm looking for and follow this answer.

Answer (score 1):

- Use `eslint-config-prettier` to turn-off eslint rules that are unnecessary or might conflict with Prettier. See 1st line in readme: [eslint-config-prettier](https://github.com/prettier/eslint-config-prettier#eslint-config-prettier).
- Use `eslint-plugin-prettier` to run Prettier as an Eslint-rule. See 1st line in readme: [eslint-plugin-prettier](https://github.com/prettier/eslint-plugin-prettier#eslint-plugin-prettier-)
- Use **both** to take advantage of both tools. See recommended configuration: [eslint-plugin-prettier](https://github.com/prettier/eslint-plugin-prettier#recommended-configuration).
  This way you use `plugin` to run Prettier as an Eslint-rule, and `config` to turn-off eslint rules that are unnecessary or might conflict with Prettier.
- You can ignore `prettier-eslint`