# Insert `··` prettier/prettier

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier, react-tsx

I have a project that has both prettier and eslint installed. The problem is that when I save a file eslint automatically changes the format of the file and it seems some rules conflict with prettier. What is the solution?

This is prettier formatting:
[image]

When saved, the file changes to:
[image]

Also this is eslintrc file

```
{
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "extends": [
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended",
    "prettier/@typescript-eslint"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/ban-ts-ignore": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/interface-name-prefix": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": ["warn", { "argsIgnorePattern": "^_" }]
  },
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["**/*.tsx"],
      "rules": {
        "react/prop-types": "off"
      }
    }
  ],
  "settings": {
    "react": {
      "version": "detect"
    }
  },
  "ignorePatterns": ["coverage/", "node_modules/", "src/serviceWorker.ts"]
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Not fully configuring ESlint and Prettier can cause a myriad of issues. To avoid all of them follow the steps mentioned in [How to use Prettier with ESLint and TypeScript in VSCode](https://khalilstemmler.com/blogs/tooling/prettier/) , also remove any extra setting in config files for ESlint, Prettier and setting.json for VScod that might override other rules.

Important: Based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44690309/1262198): ****Uninstall** `prettier-eslint`** extension.

Comment: You saved my 45 minutes at least:) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try change VSCode default formatter to ESLint:

### 1. By VSCode command line

1. Open `go to file` command line
2. Input and search:

```
> format Document With
```

3. Change your default formatter to tool which report error:

[image]

### 2. By go to setting, search for `formatter`, change it to `ESLint` or other tool which report error.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is caused by the `endOfLine` rule in prettier. The end of line can be LF, CR, or CRLF. The error message relates to this issue. It occurs when you create a new line and one of the end of line characters (LF, CR, or CRLF) is automatically added at the end of the previous line to indicate the end of the line. This can vary depending on the operating system you are using.

To resolve this, you can add the following code to the rules array inside the `.eslintrc.js` file.

```
// .. 
rules:[
//  ... other rules here
prettier/prettier': [
  'error',  // alternativly change to 'warn' if you want only warning 
  {
    endOfLine: 'auto',   <---- this is the solution
    // ... put other prettier rules here like "semi":flase,
  },
],
```

]

Answer (score 0):

One workaround could be to concatenate strings with the addition operator (`+`) instead of using template strings:

```js
try {
  const response = await api.get(
    API_BOARDS +
      boardSearchParam.boardId +
      `?assignees=${boardSearchParam.assigneeIds.toString()}/`
  );
} catch (err) {
  // ...
}
```

Depending on your ESLint rules, you might get an error saying that you should use template strings instead of the addition operator. In that case, you can create a variable and use the addition assignment operator (`+=`):

```js
try {
  let url = API_BOARDS + boardSearchParam.boardId;
  url += `?assignees=${boardSearchParam.assigneeIds.toString()}/`

  const response = await api.get(url);
} catch (err) {
  // ...
}
```

It's a matter of taste, but I think this is even a bit nicer to read.

Comment: Why the downvote? The question is "What is the solution?" One solution is to use the addition operator and/or addition assignment operator instead of template strings.

Answer (score 0):

`.prettierrc`

```
{
  "printWidth": 160
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I uploaded locally the latest version of prettier

```
npm install --save-dev --save-exact prettier
```

then checked if all is fine as expected :

```
npm view prettier version
```

then accepted the quick fix proposed by VS Code, it was fine.