# In VSCode, how do I effectively run eslint --fix and prettier --write on "Format Document"?

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

For context, I've locally installed prettier, eslint, and their respective VS Code extensions. I used the word "effectively" in my title because I don't *literally* need to run `eslint --fix; prettier --write` on "Format Document," I merely want the current file to change as though I did.

There are plenty of questions about running eslint and prettier *on save*, but I have autosave turned on: pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> feels unnatural. On the other hand, I run "Format Document" all the time.

Is there a way I can have "Format Document" run `eslint --fix` and `prettier --write` (in that order<sup>1</sup>) on the current file? I know I can put this in my Visual Studio code `settings.json` file:

```json
  "[typescript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint"
  },
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint"
  },
```

or this:

```json
  "[typescript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
```

but that runs `eslint --fix` *or* `prettier --write` on "Format Document." I want to run both. Is this possible?

---

I've read [the prettier documentation on integrating with linters](https://prettier.io/docs/en/integrating-with-linters.html), and some of those links appear to be relevant to my question, but those same links are recommended against. Also, most of those projects (and most of the questions on this site) run in the opposite order: I want `eslint --fix` *then* `prettier`, but everyone else wants `prettier` *then* `eslint --fix`. And to be honest, I'm not sure why. [I've explained my reasoning in a github issue](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-eslint/issues/945), but this is tangential to my actual question. This is why I bring it up: if the answer goes against the recommendations of prettier, please include some justification for why the prettier recommendations don't apply.

---

<sup>1</sup>: As I mentioned in the beginning, I don't really care about the order in which these run, I care about the result. The file should have the same formatting as running `eslint --fix; prettier --write` on the CLI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VSCode doesn't support chaining multiple formatters. More at [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57616665/3784008).

But chaining formatters isn't the answer to your problem. If you're [using Prettier and ESLint properly](https://prettier.io/docs/en/comparison) then they do not overlap in their ruleset. You can use [eslint-plugin-prettier](https://github.com/prettier/eslint-plugin-prettier) to format the document with only ESLint and it will run Prettier as an ESLint rule.  Adding [eslint-config-prettier](https://github.com/prettier/eslint-config-prettier) disables any ESLint rules that would conflict with Prettier.

Aftewards, running `eslint --fix` would apply both your ESLint and Prettier rules in a single format.

If you would like to use ESLint with other filetypes then you need to find [ESLint plugins](https://github.com/dustinspecker/awesome-eslint) that work for those filetypes. They require installation and configuration unique to each plugin. An example is [eslint-plugin-jsonc](https://github.com/ota-meshi/eslint-plugin-jsonc#configuration) to add support for JSONC.

In `package.json`:

```json
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.10.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.10.0",
    "eslint": "^8.53.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.1",
    "prettier": "^3.0.3",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2"
  }
}
```

In `.eslintrc.json`:

```json
{
  "extends": [
    "plugin:prettier/recommended" // must be last element in "extends"
  ],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "plugins": [
    "@typescript-eslint"
  ],
  "settings": {
    "import/parsers": {
      "@typescript-eslint/parser": [
        ".ts"
      ]
    },
  }
}
```

Set your Prettier rules in `.prettierrc.json`, for example:

```json
{
  "printWidth": 100
}
```

Now `eslint --fix` will format the document in a single pass.

For VSCode, install both the `dbaeumer.vscode-eslint` and the `esbenp.prettier-vscode` extensions. These each require you to have the corresponding npm package installed, whether locally in your app or globally on your device. You may also need to configure VSCode so that it can find the packages, depending on how they were installed.

Then when you run `Format Document With` and select ESLint it will apply both your ESLint and Prettier rules with the equivalent of `eslint --fix`. For example, leaving a trailing space will trigger this INFO alert:

```
Delete `·` eslint (prettier/prettier)
```

Formatting the document with ESLint resolves the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This is the path I went down after posting, but I hadn't stabilized things to the point where I was ready to share my answer. `But the answer is: do not use both.` Can you expand on this with as much detail as possible? I've installed prettier, eslint, and their respective VS Code extensions. Are you only referring to the prettier *extension*? The eslint-plugin-prettier readme says, "[This] does not install Prettier or ESLint for you. You must install these yourself.

Comment: I'm going with the assumption that you were telling me to uninstall the prettier extension. If that's what you meant, how do I format `jsonc` (json with comments), and other non-js/ts file extensions that eslint doesn't support out-of-the-box? I've googled and seen that their are npm packages for adding additional eslint extension support, but are they going to defer to my `prettier` configuration file? What do you do for this situation?

Comment: I've updated my answer to provide more explanation, including a pointer on JSONC.

Comment: Yeah that's great. I unintentionally implied I want to run `eslint --fix; prettier --write` on every file type, but that actually isn't true: I want to run `eslint --fix; prettier --write` on every file type *that will be modified by both*. For example, if `prettier` already lints and formats `json` files, I don't need to run `eslint` on it when I "Format Document." Since your edit says it's okay to leave the prettier extension installed, I will just use it directly for those file types.

Comment: One last question: I have followed your steps for ts/js files, but when I run "Format Document" on them, the VS Code Output tab prints information in the Prettier tab, not the ESLint tab. Is this expected or does it indicate things aren't set up correctly?

Comment: I suggest you carefully define and ask a new question. Comments are not for back and forth discussions

Comment: But I'm asking for clarification about your answer. Let me ask a different way: You say, "For example, leaving a trailing space will trigger this INFO alert." *Where* will it print that info alert?

Comment: You're right. I spoke out of turn. I'm sorry. First set ESLint to debug mode with this in your settings: `"eslint.debug": true` Next either run `Developer: Reload Window` or quit/restart VSCode to apply the change. You'll then open the panel (⇧+⌘+U) and select the `OUTPUT` tab, and finally select `ESLint` from the drop-down menu. Now when you open a `.ts` file and make a change, like adding an unnecessary space, you'll see the debug output of what ESLint is doing. If it is under `Prettier` instead then check `editor.defaultFormatter` for the file types to ensure you format with ESLint.

Comment: NP, thanks for the help!